# F# equivalent of a public C# generic method

Tags: generics, f#, c#-to-f#

I am attempting to create a public method in a class in F#.  The equivalent in C# would be:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(string name, Thing<T> thingToProcess)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

In F#, I am trying:

```
member public this.MyMethod<'T>((name : System.String), (thingToProcess : Thing<'T>)) =
    (* Do similar stuff *)
    ()
```

This code generates the compiler error:

> error FS0670: This code is not sufficiently generic.  The type variable 'T could not be
>   generalized because it would escape its scope.

If I try the following, I can compile:

```
member public this.MyMethod((name : System.String), (thingToProcess : Thing<_>)) =
    (* Some code *)
    ()
```

But, trying to call the method from C# like the following fails:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(Thing<T> thingToProcess)
{
    _instanceOfFSharpClass.MyMethod("A string", thingToProcess);
}
```

with compiler error:

> The best overloaded method match for 'MyFSharpClass.MyMethod(string, Thing)' has
>   some invalid arguments.

Suggestions?  How do I create this type of method in F#?  If this method cannot be created in F#, what is a reasonable workaround?  I need to avoid casting `Thing<T>` to `Thing<object>` if at all possible.

**Edit:**

Here is more of the F# code.  I'll try to stick to likely-relevant portions. `EnumWithFlags` is an enumeration from a C# assembly with the `[FlagsAttribute]`.  `cacheOne` is populated in other methods not listed here.  `IInterface` is defined in the C# assembly and has only one method, `void ReceiveThing<T>(string name, Thing<T> thingToProcess)`.  The function `TranslateThing` has signature `val TranslateThing : (Guid -> Thing<'T> -> TranslatedThing<'T>)`.  Does this help?

```
type TranslatedThing<'T> =
    | FirstThing of Thing<'T>
    | SecondThing of Thing<System.String>
    | ThirdThing of Thing<byte[]>
    | FourthThing of Thing<System.String>
    | IgnoreThing

[<AbstractClass>]
type public MyAbstractClass() =
    let cacheOne = new ConcurrentDictionary<EnumWithFlags, Dictionary<Guid, IInterface>>()

    member public this.MyMethod<'T>((name : System.String), (thingToProcess : Thing<'T>)) =
        cacheOne.Keys.Where(fun key -> match key with
                                       | k when (k &&& thingToProcess.EnumWithFlagsProperty) = EnumWithFlags.None -> false
                                       | _ -> true)
                     .SelectMany(fun key -> cacheOne.[key].AsEnumerable())
                     .Distinct(
                         {
                             new IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<Guid, IInterface>> with
                                 member x.Equals(a, b) = a.Key = b.Key
                                 member x.GetHashCode y = y.Key.GetHashCode()
                         })
                     .AsParallel()
                     .Select(new Func<KeyValuePair<Guid, IInterface>, Tuple<IInterface, TranslatedThing<_>>>(fun kvp -> new Tuple<IInterface, TranslatedThing<'T>>(kvp.Value, TranslateThing kvp.Key thingToProcess)))
                     .Where(new Func<Tuple<IInterface, TranslatedThing<'T>>, bool>(fun t -> t.Item2 <> IgnoreThing))
                     .ForAll(new Action<Tuple<IInterface, TranslatedThing<'T>>>(fun t ->
                                 match t.Item2 with
                                 | FirstThing(x) -> t.Item1.ReceiveThing(name, x)
                                 | SecondThing(x) -> t.Item1.ReceiveThing(name, x)
                                 | ThirdThing(x) -> t.Item1.ReceiveThing(name, x)
                                 | FourthThing(x) -> t.Item1.ReceiveThing(name, x)
                                 | _ -> ()))
```

**Another edit:**

After much distillation, I think I see roughly what is causing the issue.  I left off the last line of `MyMethod` because taking it out did not solve the error.  This line was:

```
cacheTwo.Remove(thingToProcess) |> ignore
```

where `cacheTwo` is defined earlier in the class:

```
let cacheTwo = new Dictionary<Thing<'T>, SpecificThingTranslator<'T>>
```

where the signature of `SpecificThingTranslator<'T>` is:

```
type SpecificThingTranslator<'T> =
 {First: TranslatedThing<'T>;
  Second: Lazy<TranslatedThing<'T>>;
  Third: Lazy<TranslatedThing<'T>>;
  Fourth: Lazy<TranslatedThing<'T>>;}
```

Eliminating the `cacheTwo` line did not solve the error because the function `TranslateThing` refers to `cacheTwo`, eventually.  Eliminating all references to `cacheTwo` eliminates the error.

I can probably find a workaround to map `Thing<'T>` to `SpecificThingTranslator<'T>`.  Nevertheless, have I missed something here?  Have I forgotten about a .NET collection (or maybe an F#-specific one) that will allow this mapping?  While the type parameter for the key and value of each pair must be the same, each KeyValuePair (or equivalent) can have a different type parameter.

Comment: I will, time permitting, edit the question for brevity and clarity once there is a clear solution.  The compiler error is a bit mystifying to an F# newcomer, and the Google-the-error-message approach did not yield any results that seemed to apply.  My hope is that another programmer encountering the error message can benefit from this question and answer.

Answer (score 7):

There must be something wrong with another part of your code. The following minimal sample has exactly the same definition of `MyMethod` and works fine (when pasted into a new script file):

```
type Thing<'T> = T of 'T

type Foo() =
  member this.MyMethod<'T>(name:string, thingToProcess:Thing<'T>) =
      ()
```

I removed the `public` modifier, because that is the default for members in F# and I also removed additional parentheses, but otherwise, nothing has changed....

Comment: Very likely.  I'll add some more detail and see if that is helpful.

Comment: Yes, if you can give a minimal sample that gives the error, that would make it possible to give some more useful answer!

Comment: Thank you.  I have added the code, however inelegant it may be.  I'm fairly new to F#, as you might guess.

Comment: @Andrew Even with the updated version, I still cannot replicate the error (I just added all necessary definitions to make your code compile...) So, you'll probably need too add a bit more (or simplify your code to find the source of the problem..)

Comment: Thanks again for giving it a shot.  I'll try to distill this code this evening.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and patience.  I have edited the question to narrow the problem.